# Estimate on difference of polar part

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, estimation

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. Define $\mathrm{pol}:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ by $\mathrm{pol}(z):=\frac{z}{\|z\|}\forall z\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$.

**Question** Is the following claim correct, and if it is, can it be improved also for small $\|y\|,\|x-y\|$? It seems to me like the estimate should break down when approaching the origin, as $\mathrm{pol}$ is not continuously extendible there, but I just want to be sure I'm not missing a more obvious derivation. Very close to the origin, $\|x-y\|,\|y\|$ can get arbitrarily small yet $\|\mathrm{pol}(x)-\mathrm{pol}(y)\|$ can be held fixed (if we travel along the rays downwards toward the origin).

**Claim** We have for some $1<C<\infty$, $$\|\mathrm{pol}(x)-\mathrm{pol}(y)\|\leq C \frac{\|x-y\|}{1+\|y\|}$$ if I: $\|x-y\|<\|y\|$ and $\|y\|\geq(C-1)^{-1}$ *or* II: $\|x-y\|\geq\|y\|$ and $C\|x-y\|-1\geq\|y\|$.

**Proof** We start from the basic estimate which is $\|\mathrm{pol}(x)-\mathrm{pol}(y)\|\leq2$ for the worst case of two antipodal points. Furthermore we have 
\begin{align}
|\mathrm{pol}(x)-\mathrm{pol}(y)| &= \frac{1}{\|y\|}\|\frac{\|y\|x-\|x\|y}{\|x\|}\| \\
&=\frac{1}{\|y\|}\|\frac{(\|y\|-\|x\|)x-\|x\|(y-x)}{\|x\|}\| \\
&\leq 2\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|y\|}\,.
\end{align}
This holds for all $x,y\neq0$. Combining these two we find $$ |\mathrm{pol}(x)-\mathrm{pol}(y)| \leq 2 \min(\{1,\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|y\|}\}) \,.$$
This results in the above claim by choosing any $C>1$.